# Delphi 7 not generating COM classes when importing Type Library

Tags: c#, com, delphi-7, .net-assembly

In C#, I have a class and its interface in my solution, and I want them to be COM visible.

I have:

1. created the interface and the class as following:

   ```
   [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("0D1ABB24-144E-4C88-A4A5-DC3ED0E61BEB")]
   [ComVisible(true)]
   public interface IMyInterface
   {
       // methods here
   }

   [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("01AA5822-83D1-42C6-A578-C9A84AB836AA")]
   [ComVisible(true)]
   public class MyClass : IMyInterface
   {
       // implementation here
   }
   ```

   (note they are both COM visible)
2. generated a GUID and informed it in the Assembly Info:

   ```
   [assembly: Guid("MY-GUID-HERE")]
   ```
3. Registered it with this command line:

   ```
   c:\regasm.exe /tlb MyAssembly.Dll
   ```
4. Imported the Type Library in Delphi 7.

A unit is generated, but it does not contain the class and functions/procedures. Calling `CoClass.Create` returned a "Class not registered" error.

Later I created a new solution with a class library, performing the same operations above, and the classes/methods where generated and I could access them.

Are there any tips about what I might have missed?

Comment: You should try adding the /codebase option to your regasm command.  Also, your DLL and your Delphi project need to be both 32-bit or both 64-bit.

I usually try to test registration of the DLL by using a VBS script to create the object.  If you building a 32-bit DLL, you have to be sure to use the cscript.exe or wscript.exe in c:\windows\syswow64--assuming a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Also, use Oleview to try and open the TLB file generated to see what it looks like--assuming you have visual studio.  I'm not familiar with the tools that Delphi ships with that would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the difference.
One TLB class I wanted to export had some constructors in a region. When I expanded it, I saw there was no overloaded constructor without parameters.
After adding a no-argument constructor, it was visible at Delphi and I could use it normally.